# How to map a SpringServlet to root and also serve static content in root?

Tags: spring, rest, servlets, static

I have a JAX-RS spring service that I've added swagger to. Swagger builds a json description of the service that has to be served as a static file. I've also included swagger ui to view the json description nicely. My issue is when mapping the servlet path to the root it will then not serve the static swagger files under /swagger. The service works just fine. Both will work if I map the service to a path that's not root such as /rest/*. I'd rather have a nice path without "/rest/" in the middle.

So when I have `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` the service is at the root `<servicename>/` and going to `<servicename>/swagger/` returns 404 not found. If I change to `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` then the service is working at `<servicename>/rest/` and swagger is visible at `<servicename>/swagger`. Is it possible to have this work without needing the service to be under `<servicename>/rest/*`?

I'm on Spring 3.0.7-RELEASE and JERSEY 1.8. Edit: Also, this is running on Weblogic 10.3.6.0.

web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

 <display-name>Data Access Service</display-name>

 <listener>
  <listener-class>com.my.Startup</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>

 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>local-deployment</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
   com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>com.my.rs</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 
</web-app>
```

application-context.xml:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

 <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/swagger/**" 
     location="/swagger/" />
     
 <!--context:annotation-config /-->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.my" />
 <tx:annotation-driven />
 
 <bean id="dasDatasource" 
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/dasExampleDatasource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dasDatasource" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
  <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="dasExampleDatasource" />
  <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
   <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.weblogic.WebLogicLoadTimeWeaver" />
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

 <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter" />

 <bean id="jpaDialect"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />

 <bean id="transactionManager" 
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

 <bean id="apiListingResourceJSON"
  class="com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON" />
 <bean id="apiDeclarationProvider"
  class="com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyApiDeclarationProvider"
  scope="singleton" />
 <bean id="resourceListingProvider"
  class="com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.JerseyResourceListingProvider"
  scope="singleton" />

 <bean id="beanConfig" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
        <property name="title" value="Swagger Sample App"/>
        <property name="version" value="1.0.0" />
        <property name="basePath" value="http://localhost:8001/myservice/v1"/>
        <property name="resourcePackage" value="com.my.rs,com.my.common.rs"/>
        <property name="scan" value="true"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Read that chapter and the next one in the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-static-resources

Comment: Yes, that was the document sections I tried before posting, but it's not working. Even adding <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> to the application-context.xml makes no difference. I don't have a custom default servlet. I should've added that this is running on weblogic 10.3.6.0. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Ah, I just re-read your question. What is mapped to / is not a spring dispatcher servlet, but a jersey servlet, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by using filter definitions rather than servlet definitions. Additionally, there was a bug in JERSEY 1.8 that caused my mount point to require a trailing forward slash (https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1410) so I updated to JERSEY 1.19. I plan to further update to 2.x as well as Spring 4.x when the features of my project are stable.

Here is the web.xml that allowed me to have a swagger ui view within the same root directory as my service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Data Access Service</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.my.Startup</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>local-deployment</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.my.rs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Redirect</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.FilterForwardOn404</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```